# how to use token based authentication using jaxrs

Tags: rabbitmq, jax-rs

I have one function that is used to get the Json data from RabbitMQ. Right now I am using basic authentication, but I would like to switch to token-based authentication.

So my question is: how do I get that authentication token?

Comment: I am trying to use RabbitMQ on my localhost, but having hard time with it, can you give me any pointers regarding that.

Comment: Follow the book in this link http://www.cybershovel.com/b/RabbitMQinAction.pdf.
You will get some idea.

Comment: I am also looking for the same. But the PDF link is is broken. Please help. We are trying to embed the Security token with the message we are sending to Rabbit MQ.